# HTML video in popup box randomly plays/doesn't play in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, popup, html5-video

This will once again be one of those question there's probably no answer to, but I'll try it anyway.

I created a custom WP plug-in that takes a folder name and outputs all videos inside the folder as images, which when clicked make a video pop-up. The video has custom controls (only play/pause and mute) and I'm using fancybox to make the video pop-up.

Everything works reliably in Opera and Firefox. The video doesn't bother playing in IE9 and, what's most annoying, it **sometimes** plays in Chrome and sometimes doesn't. (btw Safari won't even pop-up, no idea why).

The plug-in is quite a piece of code, but the end result is a bunch of links with an image inside and a hidden div that contains the links relevant to the current video. Then there's the video container, which is the code for the pop-up. Upon clicking one of the links, the src of the video is swapped for the one that is in the hidden content of the link.

It's quite hard to explain, so please have a look at the code on the website:
http://londoncreativedigital.com/downloads/creativeshowcase/

If you're still reading, here's the plug-in's code
https://github.com/marian-cerny/simple-video-embed

Video playing/pausing is handled in assets/player-controller.js.

I would greatly appreciate any help. I just can't logically explain what can be the reason for this. I tried to debug the JS, but couldn't come up with anything.
For a second I thought that adding a webm video would help, but it doesn't. It behaves the same way, even after adding a webm and removing the mp4 version. (tried on localhost, the online version doesn't have the webm vids).

Comment: mp4 has to be good for chrome anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hardly ever need to blame your markup or javascript, suppose there is something different than this. I've been it such situations couple of times. All right, here is what I did.

1. opened video directly in chrome and FF.
2. open the developer bar on both, and look up the net(network) tab, where you suppose to see headers and other loading information.
3. in my case here is only one request in FF, and multiply from Chrome and there is canceled or pending only.
4. tryed the same with ogg clip, it is good in FF though chunked, and bit better in Chrome, part of requests are in pending, part canceled and fiew is good.

What could be wrong here, all right, as I said I do have similar problems in the past, I worked with professional movie maker, who do very good with all that codecs stuff. I just showed him perfectly working mp4 video from the videojs.com and he fixed his somehow by changing encoder or something like this. Unfortunately, I could not connect him how and ask, but probably it gives you some ideas. Please whenever you will be able to solve it, update status over here, I was bit intrigued all that times but had no chance to resolve my curiosity.

Your video was only once worked for me, but I am not sure if it was `mp4` or `ogg` at that point. Also I am on win7 with latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: So you're saying it's an encoding issue ? That's what I thought too. But then why would it do the same with webm videos ?

 It would be awesome if someone could recommend a free video converted that produces HTML5 videos that work in Chrome. I use Freemake, but apparently it's not good enough.

Comment: It may be something related to caching ? I noticed that after I upload a video if always plays for the first time, but not on consequent loads.

Comment: Yes, I did not think about why ogg has troubles as well. As a guess, might it be some sort of headers issue, either something blocking on server side, but than why it is okay in FF?

Comment: Ahh, major ball ache. I'm changing the website from pop-up to slideshow. I think it's because I'm changing URLs of the same video tag and Chrome doesn't like it...

Comment: So, since there's probably no solution, I might as well mark this answer as accepted. Thanks for the help. Such a shame, I put so much work in this plug-in...

Comment: thanks @MarianoGrandioso, so what's your update status? when you ended up with no popup solution if it started to work? On your dev link it seems to be the same. There is no shame over there, cause sometimes very stupid thing could make your week work, so the only you need just fix it somewhere and do not fall in the same situation again.

Comment: I actually may have something... we just bought flowplayer and it didn't play the videos, even without the popup. So I emailed support and they got back to me saying that the headers sent out by the server are wrong. I briefed our admin to take a look at this. This may be the solution to the popup problem as well.